# Reload RAID at Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I use Ubuntu with one big mdadm (RAID with two big disks) but: I've got new disk with OS (Ubuntu of course). I'm trying to reload my mdadm. Without success.

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [linear] [multipath] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid0 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      7813770240 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
      
unused devices: <none>
```

Looks good.

```
# mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md127
mdadm: Unknown keyword mdadm
mdadm: Unknown keyword mdadm
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jun 10 11:18:15 2023
        Raid Level : raid0
        Array Size : 7813770240 (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Jun 10 11:18:15 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : -unknown-
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : none

              Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
              UUID : 786a4ae2:c98e11a2:b57c5f25:2cbcea22
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

It looks good too but:

```
# mount /dev/md127 /somewhere/
mount: /somewhere: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

I need it back.
Do you know what I must to do?

There is maybe some password. How can I know about it?